# Multiple Promise Objects - wait for all

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Excuse the long question but I believe that this information is vital in determining the error in the application.

**Loop Configuration Settings:**

```
window.config = {
"Environments": [
    "LH5",
    "LH8",
    "AMS"
],
"Clusters": [
    4,
    4,
    4
]
};
```

**The Loop:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < window.config.Environments.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < window.config.Clusters[i] + 1; j++) {
```

**Promise Object Declaration:**

```
 promiseObj.physical[window.config.Environments[i] + "#Cluster" + j] = $http.get('url/search?idc=' + window.config.Environments[i] + '&type=Physical&cluster=' + j).success(function(i,j) {
            return function(data) {
```

**Each Promise Object then has an additional loop..**

```
angular.forEach($scope.servers, function(item) {

                countcores[window.config.Environments[i] + "#Cluster" + j] = parseInt(countcores[window.config.Environments[i] + "#Cluster" + j]) + parseInt(item.cores);
                countmemory[window.config.Environments[i] + "#Cluster" + j] = parseInt(countmemory[window.config.Environments[i] + "#Cluster" + j]) + parseInt(item.memory);

            });
```

**End Promise Object**

```
}(i,j));
} } // End for loops
```

**Q All Function**

```
$q.all(promiseObj).then(function(results) {

    for (var i = 0; i < window.config.Environments.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < window.config.Clusters[i] + 1; j++) {
        alert(countvirtualcores[window.config.Environments[i] + "#Cluster" + j]);

        alert(countcores[window.config.Environments[i] + "#Cluster" + j]);

        }}
  });
```

**When running the Q All function I get:**

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
```

Additionally I do not get access to:

```
 countvirtualcores[window.config.Environments[i] + "#Cluster" + j]
```

Which returns undefined.

**Questions:**

a) Why doesn't the promise object work as expected?

b) Is this the right solution to this problem?

Comment: Not too sure if this is your issue, or adding to it, but `$http.success()` does not return a promise. My understanding of `$q.all()` is it requires an array or object of promises.

Comment: Full code: http://paste.ofcode.org/kKDmKrFD8vqev5m6n6LzbD

Answer (score 1):

I think you get a problem with your **Promise Object declaration**.

`$http` service return **promises**, but in your example, you are not returning promises, you're using the `.success()` callback method, and try to return a result.

So, you have to build a promises array, and pass it to your `$q.all()` method, which is built to handle many promises.

I've made a little example :

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, $q, Service) {

  var promises = [];

  for (var i = 1; i < 10; ++i){
    //Add promises to our array
    promises.push(Service.get(i));
  }

  $q.all(promises).then(function(response){
    //Here, response is a raw array
    //Retrieve response data by mapping the results
    var data = response.map(function(elm){
      return elm.data;
    });
    //Print my array data
    console.log(data);
  });

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**Service**

```
(function(){

  function Service($http) {

    function get(n){
      //Return a promise
      return $http.post('path_to_url_example', n);
    }

    return {
      get: get
    }

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Service', Service);

})();
```

So here, we are passing param to our **POST** request, then we will be able to retrieve these data into your `$q.all()` method.

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new to Angular JS. The code that I posted is all stored in controller.js - are you suggesting I spread it out to controller.js and service.js?

Comment: Generally speaking your controller should only be used to facilitate communication between your services, directives etc. You should have as little logic in there as possible. Certainly your $http requests should be made in services. - Edit: Thats not entirely correct as you can inject services into directives. But you should abstract as much logic out of your controller to make your app more testable and re-useable. Less duplication of logic etc.

Comment: If you want, you can do the same just by using Controller, but when the code tends to be more complex, you should use service in order to make your code cleaner and more reusable. Moreover, all angular Service are **Singletons**, it can be useful if you want to share data between controllers for example.

Comment: Also instead of using the `.success()` and `.error()` using the `.then()` of the native promise, as above, allows to you chain for more complex behavior. You can also use the `.catch()` to provide more obvious error handling instead of the second option callback of the `.then()` method. Dunno, thought it may be useful info.

Comment: Sorry for being completely new to this, but I'm getting: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ServiceProvider <- Service

Comment: Be careful to the declaration of your module, between the **getter** and **setter** syntax. Moreover, when you have declare your service, you should inject it into your Controller. In my example, i've declared a **controller** which get a **Service**. Then, i've declared my **Service**, but just by using **setter** syntax of my module declaration

Comment: Service:

http://paste.ofcode.org/L8XkJwuyzckiaDdhTv48Gz

Controller:

http://paste.ofcode.org/bVfckhvNegFnGJrrh2jZuZ

Comment: @PaulBoutes - I am still struggling with this

Comment: At lines 19 & 20 in your controller, replace the **Service.get()** by **HomeService.get()**. You set your service name as **HomeService** and not **Service**.

Comment: @PaulBoutes - thanks but I still receive: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: HomeServiceProvider <- HomeService

Comment: Also, be sure to include your **script tag** in your html.

Comment: Script tag starts with: <section data-ng-controller="HomeController">

Comment: Yes but if you have create another file wuth your services, be sure ton include it into your index.html.

Comment: I only have home.client.view.html in this module - what do I need to include?

Comment: @PaulBoutes - can you help?

Comment: This is quite hard to find the error without the full code. Take a look about your module declaration. Take a look about this doc : [Unknow provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr)

Comment: @PaulBoutes - you have the full code for controller.js and service.js

Comment: You can see the plunker, your module is correctly initialized : [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/obQsFM6Q6ZWlXEWVNbKw?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks - it makes my HeaderController not work- do you know why?

Comment: @Corbin In your module deffiniton your missing the empty array. That is in the paste.ofcode links youve put `angular.module('core')` it should be `angular.module('core', [])`. The array is for any other modules you wish to inject into your app. If you don't have any you need to provide an empty array. That has cause me issues in the past with injecting things. Also you can concact your service and controller to `angular.module('t', []).controller().service();` etc or `var app = angular.module(); app.controller(); app.service();` There's no need to define your app twice. Hope that may help;

Comment: @ste2425 - When I add the empty array I get `'HeaderController' is not a function, got undefined`

Comment: @Corbin i created a fiddle that is now working from your two `paste.ofcode` links. http://jsfiddle.net/0qedr2jt/

There were a couple of issues. First the missing array on your module definition. Second in your `.controller()` you've wrapped everything in an array with strings then your controller function. This is so angular's dependency system will work when your JS is minified and is good practice. However you hadn't provided all your dependencies as strings in the array.

Comment: Thanks @ste2425 - forgive my ignorance but where would this fit in

controller.js
server.js

Comment: @Corbin No problem :) That depends on how you include your JS onto your page. If your using a build system like `browserify` or just including loads on different pages in script tags. If the latter i generally have three files (depending on the complexity of the app). The first being app.js in it i put `var app = angular.module()` and include that in my page. That makes my app a global variable and in all my other files i can do `app.controller()` `app.directive()` `app.service()` and so on. Hope that explains it. Updated the fiddle with comments: http://jsfiddle.net/0qedr2jt/1/

Comment: @Corbin also one other thing i forgot to mention. Your original service definition had trailing brackets `()` in the paste.ofcode link. So it though it was a function and tried to executing it throwing an exception

Comment: @ste2425 - I can't get it to work in my environment, I am getting `[ng:areq] Argument 'HeaderController' is not a function, got undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89001/discussion-between-ste2425-and-corbin).